# PowerShell - how to continuously copy files from the TEMP folder to another directory

Tags: powershell

I am trying to continuously copy files from the TEMP folder on Windows Server 2019 to a folder of my choosing.

I have tried the following code. I have added top it extensively from the original code to try and diagnose the issue but I have no idea what to do next

```
# Define the source and destination directories
$sourceDirectory = 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp'
$destinationDirectory = 'C:\Users\Administrator\copied'

# Create an instance of the FileSystemWatcher class
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = $sourceDirectory
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true

# Specify the type of changes to monitor
$watcher.NotifyFilter = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'

# Filter the file types to monitor
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"

# Define the action to take when a file is created or modified
$action = {
    param($sender, $eventArgs)
$destinationDirectory = 'C:\Users\Administrator\copied'
    $eventType = $eventArgs.ChangeType
    $filePath = $eventArgs.FullPath

    if ($filePath -and (Test-Path $filePath) -and ($eventType -eq 'Created' -or $eventType -eq 'Changed')) {
        # Construct the destination file path
        $destFilePath = Join-Path -Path $destinationDirectory -ChildPath (Split-Path -Path $filePath -Leaf)

        # Copy the file to the destination directory
        try {
            Copy-Item -Path $filePath -Destination $destFilePath -Force
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host ("Failed to copy file. Error: " + $_.Exception.Message)
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Event detected with no file path, or the file does not exist, or the event type is not supported. Ignoring."
        Write-Host "Full event details: $eventArgs"
    }
}

# Add the event handlers for the Created and Changed events
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName 'Created' -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName 'Changed' -Action $action

# Start monitoring the files
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

# Keep the PowerShell console open
while ($true) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

However I get the following errors and I have no idea where to go from here. Any suggestions?

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
31     aa937f11-a26...                 NotStarted    False                                ...
32     2db275b2-991...                 NotStarted    False                                ...
Event detected with no file path, ignoring.
Full event details: System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs
Event detected with no file path, or the file does not exist, or the event type is not supported. Ignoring.
Full event details: System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs
Event detected with no file path, or the file does not exist, or the event type is not supported. Ignoring.
Full event details: System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs
```

The error messages have been here all along but I am not sure what else I can do

Comment: just my 2 cents but it might be a lot simpler if instead of setting a SystemFileWatcher + an infinite loop you could just create a scheduled task that runs every 5 minutes and checks if there are new files in the last 5 minutes

Comment: I am monitoring what temp files are created during an installation process - which itself takes 2 mins

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix, however this and the original script, wont copy a rename, if you rename a file in the source, it wont retrigger a copy/rename in the destination. I also updated the error handling to add to a log file.

```
# Define the source and destination directories
$sourceDirectory = 'C:\TestMonitor'
$destinationDirectory = 'C:\TestCopy'

# Create an instance of the FileSystemWatcher class
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = $sourceDirectory
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true

# Specify the type of changes to monitor
$watcher.NotifyFilter = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'

# Filter the file types to monitor
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"

# Define the action to take when a file is created or modified
$action = {
    param($sender, $eventArgs)
    Try {
    $destinationDirectory = 'C:\TestCopy'
    $eventType = $eventArgs.ChangeType
    $filePath = $eventArgs.FullPath

    if ($filePath -and (Test-Path $filePath) -and ($eventType -match 'Created|Changed')) 
        {
            #Copy the file to the destination directory
            Copy-Item -Path $filePath -Destination $destinationDirectory -Force
        }
        else 
        {
            "Event detected with no file path, or the file does not exist, or the event type is not supported. Ignoring." | Out-File "$($destinationDirectory)\FileCopy.log" -Append
            "Full event details: $eventArgs" | Out-File "$($destinationDirectory)\FileCopy.log" -Append
        }
    } 
    Catch
    {
        "Failed to copy file. Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" | Out-File "$($destinationDirectory)\FileCopy.log" -Append
    }
}

# Add the event handlers for the Created and Changed events
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName 'Created' -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName 'Changed' -Action $action

# Start monitoring the files
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

# Keep the PowerShell console open
while ($true) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```